Why danach instead of darüber?
I read the below sentence which means "Facebook asks for it to make sure you are over 13 years old" but why danach is used why not darüber?
Facebook fragt danach, um sicherzustellen, dass Sie über 13 Jahre alt sind.

That's because the relevant verb phrase is nach etwas fragen — to ask for something.

Er fragt sie nach ihrem Alter.
Er fragt sie danach, wie alt sie ist.

You have to learn those verb phrases with their prepositions. There is no system to it. You can see that from the fact that German uses nach — after but English uses for — für. German and English are closely related and yet the preposition is different.

Of course, in English, you can ask after someone (to get information about how they’re doing), ask for something (to be supplied), and ask about something (to find out more details about it). I would guess the latter would use über in German (as expected by the asker), but use a different verb than fragen, perhaps Fragen über X stellen?

It's über X ausfragen.

Even the original English sentence sounds a bit weird to me, because it is somewhat unclear what "it" is (it is obviously clear from the context, but there is no valid reference). You would somewhat expect "...asks for your age...")
A proper way to express the sentence in German would be

Facebook fragt nach, um sicherzustellen, dass...

using nachfragen (which doesn't take an object, so doesn't need the equivalent of the unclear "it") and implicitly referring to a "asks for your age".
Then, why "nach" instead of "über" - well, that is the proper preposition to use, there is, as mentioned above, even the composite verb nachfragen.

There are several things to consider here:
First, there is the phrase nach etwas fragen, which means "to ask about sth.". This is a fixed phrase, similar to the English phrase with "about". The english and the german prepositions differ here, but that is the case with a lot of verbs.
The second is the "da-word" (actually there is no other name for these words that I know of). It acts as a correlate. This is a word which stands in for a longer phrase in a relative sentence. Here is an example:

Ich frage nach dem Namen.

Here the object which is asked about is "dem Namen", which is a simple Nomen. But other things one could ask for might be more complex and wouldn't fit into the place a simple object provides. For these occasions there are "correlates" - words, which stand in for the object, but carry no original meaning, they only point to a relative sentence somewhere else. When the da-words are used in this capacity they are built from the normal preposition plus the prefix "da-". Since here the preposition is "nach", it is "da-nach":

Ich frage danach, wie dein Name ist.

On a side note: "über 13 Jahre alt" is technically correct but very quirkily phrased. There is "über 30" and similar, but usually without "Jahre" and "alt", only the number, e.g:

Er ist schon über 50.

I'd consider this a - bad - anglicism. A better wording would be:

Facebook fragt danach, um sicherzustellen, daß Sie älter als 13 Jahre sind.

